# Count of non Null values in a Row

Tags: sql, sqlite

Is there a better way of doing this?

```
select count(First)+count(id)+count(Last)+count(Telephone) 
from client 
where id ="1";
```

Comment: Get the count of non Null values in a Row

Comment: I would also be just as happy with the count of Null values in the row.

Comment: If `id = "1"` is satisfied, then `id` cannot be null.  Is `id` the primary key column, so that there can be at most one row with `id = "1"` (or any other specific value), and in fact no `id` can ever be NULL?

Comment: id is primary key column. I am trying to rank rows by which have "more data" in them, meaning less null fields or more non null fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is *better*, but the intent may be clearer to someone reading it later:

```
select 
  (case when First is null then 1 else 0 end) + 
  (case when id is null then 1 else 0 end) + 
  (case when Last is null then 1 else 0 end) + 
  (case when Telephone is null then 1 else 0 end) 
from client 
where id ="1";
```

Comment: That does look much cleaner. I was looking for a solution in which I did not need to spell out each column though. Thanks.

Comment: Sure - no worries.  I know how to do this in tsql; does it need to be sqlite?